# How setup spray-json to set null when json element is not present?

Tags: json, scala, spray, spray-json

Here is [spray-json example](http://spray.io/documentation/1.1-SNAPSHOT/spray-httpx/spray-json-support/). Here is [NullOptions](https://github.com/spray/spray-json#nulloptions) trait.

The problem is when I declare a case class say

```
object MyJsonProtocol extends DefaultJsonProtocol  {
  implicit val some: RootJsonFormat[Some] = jsonFormat2(Some)
}

case class Some (
                name:String,
                age:Int
                )
```

and json do not contains a field for example:

```
{
    "name":"John"
}
```

I get: `java.util.NoSuchElementException: key not found: age`

So I have to add an `Option` and `NullOption` trait like that:

```
object MyJsonProtocol extends DefaultJsonProtocol with NullOptions  {
  implicit val some: RootJsonFormat[Some] = jsonFormat2(Some)
}

case class Some (
                name:String,
                age:Option[Int]
                )
```

Everything works. But I do not want to have a case classes where all member are `Option`. Is there a way to configure spray json unmarshalling to just set nulls without additional `Option` type?

**P.S.**

I understand that in general `Option` is better then null check, but in my case it is just monkey code.

Also complete example of marshalling during response processing is [here](http://spray.io/documentation/1.2-M8/spray-client/)

Answer (score 2):

The only way I can think of is to implement your own Protocol via `read/write`, which might be cumbersome. Below is a simplified example. Note that I changed the `age` to be an `Integer` instead of an `Int` since `Int` is an `AnyVal`, which is not nullable by default. Furthermore, I only consider the `age` field to be nullable, so you might need to adopt as necessary. Hope it helps.

```
 case class Foo (name:String, age: Integer)

 object MyJsonProtocol extends DefaultJsonProtocol {
    implicit object FooJsonFormat extends RootJsonFormat[Foo] {
      def write(foo: Foo) =
        JsObject("name" -> JsString(foo.name),
                 "age"  -> Option(foo.age).map(JsNumber(_)).getOrElse(JsNull))

      def read(value: JsValue) = value match {
        case JsObject(fields) =>
          val ageOpt: Option[Integer] = fields.get("age").map(_.toString().toInt) // implicit conversion from Int to Integer
          val age: Integer = ageOpt.orNull[Integer]
          Foo(fields.get("name").get.toString(), age)
        case _ => deserializationError("Foo expected")
      }
    }
  }

  import MyJsonProtocol._
  import spray.json._

  val json = """{ "name": "Meh" }""".parseJson
  println(json.convertTo[Foo]) // prints Foo("Meh",null)
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems you're out of luck

From the doc you linked:

> spray-json will always read missing optional members as well as `null` optional members as `None`

You can customize the json writing, but not the reading.